# prerequisites for reading davis kirk

Tags: algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

I would like to study some of the basics of algebraic topology and would like to read the book by Davis-Kirk. I realize that it assumes the reader is already familiar with homology, CW complexes and (in specific parts) differential topology. I actually am already somewhat familiar with these topics but nevertheless I feel I might use a brushing up. So here's my question:

> What is a good (possibly concise -- not in the May sense...) book covering the topology prerequisites necessary to read Davis-Kirk?

I feel I need to read more about CW complexes (and I can deal with differential topology as it comes along, so I don't feel a potential book must cover that)

Comment: Hatcher will have you covered for the homology and CW complexes, not so much the differential topology. I would maybe pick up Milnor's book on Morse theory or [Munkres' notes](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/difftop.pdf) on Milnor's differential topology lectures

Comment: @DanielRust: thanks. I tried reading a bit of Kirk-Davis and, while I think I like the order of the topics, I am finding the style of the presentation obnoxious. I've been trying to read Dieck's topology, although the density of the presentation and the lack of pictures is quite fatiguing.

Comment: In my experience, Davis & Kirk are the best / most pleasant book on algebraic topology. In the first 10 pages on spectral sequences, you learn a lot, and it's written much better that MacCleary's AUGTSS. With Hatcher, I never had the patience, and arguments are not algebraic enough IMO. I think you can quickly learn a lot from *Lectures on Algebraic Topology* (Matveev - 2006), and there is also *Basic Algebraic Topology* (Shastri - 2014).